# String permutation spark udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, udf

i'm convering a pig script to spark 1.6 using scala, i have a dataframe which contains a string, and i want to swap characters in a certain order.
example :

```
+----------------+
|            Info|
+----------------+
|8106f510000dc502|
+----------------+
```

i want to convert it like this order [3,1,5,7,6,(8-16),4,2]

```
+----------------+
|            Info|
+----------------+
|08f150000dc50241|
+----------------+
```

This is my pig UDF with java and it's working:

```
public class NormalizeLocInfo extends EvalFunc<String>
{
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            char [] ca = ((String)input.get(0)).toCharArray();
            return (
                    new StringBuilder().append(ca[3]).append(ca[0]).append(ca[5]).append(ca[7]).append(ca[6]).append(ca[8]).append(ca[9]).append(ca[10])
               .append(ca[11]).append(ca[12]).append(ca[13]).append(ca[14]).append(ca[15]).append(ca[16]).append(ca[4]).toString().toUpperCase()
               );
        }catch(Exception e){throw new IOException("UDF:Caught exception processing input row :"+input.get(0), e);}
    }
  }
```

How i can change it to spark udf using scala ?
Thank ou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can define a UDF function in spark for your function

```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val exec = udf((input : String) => {
      if (input == null || input.trim == "") ""
      else {
        Try{
          val ca = input.toCharArray
          List(3,1,5,7,6,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,4,2).map(a=>ca(a-1)).mkString
        } match{
          case Success(data) => data
          case Failure(e)  =>
            println(e.printStackTrace())
            ""
        }
      }
    })
```

You can use the function with withColumn() as

```
val dfNew = df.withColumn("newCol", exec($"oldCol"))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hello ;my program cannot recognize `import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}` and not found value try ; thank you

Comment: Did you try importing import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try} and Try not try

Comment: thank you @Shankar for your answer and time; i got an empty column when i use your code. may you explain me your method and why i got an empty column. thank you